How to handle large international luggage bag while switching from international to domestic flight for a self connection?
My mom is returning back to India from the US. She has direct Air India flight from US to Delhi (Terminal 3). Then there's a "self connection" (a separate booking) from Delhi T3 to T2 (Terminal 2) on Indigo domestic airline that takes her to her city of residence in India.
She has one medium bag (checked in), one small carry-on bag that she brought with her. While returning, due to additional items she wants to take back, I'm thinking of providing her my large international bag to be checked in.
My understanding is that this large international checked in bag will not be in an issue on the Air India international flight from the US to Delhi. However, if she claims this bag in Delhi T3 and goes through customs, and then takes to Delhi T2 and plans to check it into Indigo domestic airlines:

will Indigo have an issue with the dimensions of the bag? Or are they just concerned about the weight? (I'm trying to ask their customer service but it's not easy and so wanted to see if someone has relevant experience here.)
if it's just the weight, we'll reduce the weight to around 12 KG and then can we just pay for the additional bag as required during check in?


Another possibility would be to send the additional items back via FedEx/UPS/..., rather than taking them on the plane.

The max dimension of a checked baggage is :
https://www.goindigo.in/baggage/baggage-allowance.html

158cm (62 inches)
(Length + Width + Height)

Unless you've bought Double or MultiSeat upgrades, your bag can't exceed 15kg

15kg allowance per person effective Oct 1st, 2020. For Double or MultiSeats bookings, extra 10 kg. Additional charges may apply for excess baggage.



if it's just the weight, we'll reduce the weight to around 12 KG and then can we just pay for the additional bag as required during check in?

If you can pre-book your checked baggage on the website or app, it will always be cheaper to do so
